# ubuntu server user session logging

Tags: server, ssh, logging

I have an ubuntu server, which acts as a gateway to access my other internal servers over ssh.

So normally, user ssh to this ubuntu server first(to a normal account) and once inside this, they ssh to other servers in the network.

How can I log all commands entered by a user, files modified, what got modified, etc. Probably something like a keylogger, but this one is for an ubuntu server

Comment: on the box issue `history`  which is available from its file as well

Comment: history is limited to commands. It won't show which file got modified, what got modified etc..  Also it won't work when user ssh to other machines. I am looking for a solution which enables me to monitor everything from my single access server